# What changes should be made to the Google Analytics tracking code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm adding Google Analytics to my site, and the script I'm copying is this:

```
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new  Date;
ga('create', 'UA-********-A', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'>
</script>
```

and from what I've been trying to understand, I think I have to change the following lines:

```
ga('create', 'UA-********-A', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

If this is the case, what are they suppose to be changed to?
Can you give me an example?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but I know you need to change the 'UA-********-A' to your account number.  For example something like, 'UA-123455676-1'.  This will come from your analytics account.

Comment: The second line, ga('send', 'pageview'), you are telling google analytics that the user is viewing a page (thus, it contributes to page views).

Comment: So on the line ga('send', 'pageview'); I should just change 'pageview' to '<link of page code is on>'?

Comment: Here's a reference to the docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/  

Also a reference to the account explorer if you might need help finding your id:  https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/

Comment: No, 'pageview' is fine.  That just tells analytics what type of content it is.  In your analytics account you should get details about the url of the page.

Comment: Here's more details on page tracking as per your question: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me out a lot.

Comment: If you are adding GA to your site, you need to use the tracking snippet provided in your property settings. You shouldn't just copy and paste from some other source.